# Detect Object and Draw Text in live camera using Augmented Reality

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, arcore

I have to build an app using AR for android and iPhone Requirement is to detect the real world objects (temperature sensor / sound sensor and etc sensors and all) Once the camera detects the object it should (show / draw) a box border for it, Includes some of the text around the border like

1. Brand of the sensor
2. Temperature if the sensor is of type temperature
3. Draw sound value in decibel if camera have detected the sound sensor and so on for the rest of the sensors.

**I have gone through the tensor flow and wikitude and Azure Custom Vision**

**Below are my findings:**

1. Azure custom vision has API call using which it compares the captured object and the response of API call returns what is the detected object with percentage of probability
2. Tensor flow solution has offline object detection but it shows the text with the border around the detected object without API call and no need to capture image using camera , It renders the text in live camera mode just in that solution I have to add few more text data object

E.g. with this Tensor Flow app I am holding a camera in front of water bottle it detects and draw text as bottle with border and I have to do the same thing for sensor and other objects the the sensor related/object. Once the sensor/object detected in camera we are planning to call api to fetch the specific details related to that object and data will be coming from API and that response I have to bind on Live camera. 
If what I am thinking is possible or anyone have any Idea how I can Achieve this?

We need this solution with AR Core.